# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 2: invalid start byte | Decoding File Size | Python

Tags: python, python-unicode

I tried file encryption method using Crypto Library. But have a problem with receiving side try to decode file size. This is my code

Sender Code

```
client.send('file.txt'.encode())
client.send(str(file_size).encode())
client.sendall(encrypted)
client.send(b'<END>')
client.close()
```

Receiver Code

```
file_name = client.recv(1024).decode()
print(file_name)
file_size = client.recv(1024).decode()
print(file_size)
```

I tried  `file_size = client.recv(1024).decode('utf8', errors='replace')` but this not worked

This is the error,

```
file.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\FileShare\reciver.py", line 18, in <module>  
    file_size = client.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution this problem. Change a while loop to the process.

this is the code I change,

```
#for_server_side
client.send(file_name.encode())
client.send(str(file_size).encode())

#for_client_side
file_name = sock.recv(100).decode()
file_size = sock.recv(100).decode()

with open(file_name, 'rb') as file:

progress = tqdm.tqdm(unit='B', unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1000, total=int(file_size))

c = 0

while c <= file_size:
    data = file.read(1024)
    if not (data):
        break
    client.sendall(data)
    c += len(data)

    progress.update(1024)
```

client and server both side make these changes and it is work properly!